# How to access property inside of this object?

Tags: javascript, shopify

Trying to access "responseJSON.original_total_price"

This is my code -

```
  const CartObject = theme.cart.getCart();
  console.log(CartObject.responseJSON.original_total_price)
```

[image: Console View]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: this isn’t a duplicate of that question. this question is about accessing an object property in an ajax request variable, so it needs to be an async function with await.

Answer (score 2):

Making it an async function fixed it.

```
  const CartObject = await theme.cart.getCart();
  CartObject.total_price
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `JSON.parse`  function on response e.g.

```
const responseParsed = JSON.parse(responseJSON.responseText)
```